# Iterator and regular for loop

Tags: java, iterator

I understand how iteration work but may be I need more knowledge about it. Can any one please show me the main difference between these two statements:

```
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(scanner.nextLine());
        numberOfItems = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
        int[] numbers = new int[numberOfItems];
        for (int i:numbers) {
            numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
        }
        System.out.println(isJolly(numbers));
    }

while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(scanner.nextLine());
        numberOfItems = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
        int[] numbers = new int[numberOfItems];
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
            numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
        }
        System.out.println(isJolly(numbers));
    }
```

**why these giving me 2 different output?**

Comment: Primitive arrays don't use an `Iterator` object.  For arrays, the enhanced for loop is syntactic sugar.  See Effective Java, Item 46.

Comment: so you are saying I ca not use Iterator with  array?but I used before and it gave me correct output.

Comment: No, there literally is no Iterator.  :)  `int[] nums` can't spawn you an Iterator.  You used the enhanced for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created empty array (array filled with zeroes).

```
    int[] numbers = new int[numberOfItems];
```

In case of

```
 for ( int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++ ) ...
```

i starts from 0 and on each iteration it is incremented (i++). Iterations are finished when i became equals or more than numbers.length (aka numberOfItems). So sequence of i values is 0,1,2,3,4,5,...

In case of

```
for (int i:numbers) {
```

You iterate on each value taken from array and you will get sequence of zeroes ( 0,0,0,0,0, ...).

And yours number[i] = will update only the number[0] element of resulting array.